# 3rd side server separating the sessions between users?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

It's a bit difficult for me to express my question, so I made a drawing:

[image]
How can i seperate the sessoins between the users that conneted to website hoted on server 1 (App 1).
The sessions created and managed by App2 that hosted on diffrent server.

Scenario ex:
**Client 1** calls `getName()` from *App1*, *App1* asks *App2* for the name, *App2* returns the name from the Session.
Each user will receive a different name stored in his own session.

Comment: Have you checked your SessionIDs?

Comment: I have seen this \ something similar in the past. Are you doing anything with Ajax in this instance, or going through an API of any variety ?

Comment: make a custom session - its not that difficult

Comment: Hi, I ask this before the implementation to know if its possible. I dont know if App1 will seperate the sessions for each client becouse the session is between App1 and App2.